# Angular + Firebase : "Missing or insufficient permissions." on page refresh

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-security

- I'm using Firebase authentication service.
- I'm using some basics rules which WORK when I'm using the app
- I have a service which fetch data from Firebase :

  ```
  export class WorkoutService {
    myWorkoutList: any[] = [];

    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}

    fetchWorkouts() {
      this.firestore
        .collection('performances)
        .doc(emailAddress)
        .collection('myDocumentCollection')
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe( (allWorkoutElements) => {

          this.myWorkoutList = allWorkoutElements;
          // some HEAVY logic (: ...

        });
    }
  }
  ```

The problem is : Whenever I reload my page, I have an error message:

> Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.

The work-around I found is to add a delay to my service call :
`setTimeout( () => this.fetchWorkouts(), 500);`

It looks like Firebase auth is taking time to "set up" after a refresh, so my request to Firebase is denied.
How can I wait for Firebase auth to complete before I do my fetch?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I wait for Firebase auth to complete before I do my fetch?

The standard way is to set an authentication state observer as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // Here the user is signed in 
    // Do you fetch
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I have an AuthService with this, but it does not trigger when I reload a page.